# Derivative Confusion

Tags: derivatives, factoring

I am confused about something.

In derivation we learnt that;

a^x = a^x . lna

Now the question that comes to mind is what is the difference when we have:

a^3 =

Comment: It is entirely unclear as to what you are asking. Could you possible rephrase?

Comment: @CameronWilliams, thanks for the reply.. Umm what I mean is our teacher told us that when you have a^x then that is equal to a^x.lna ... so what I am asking is... what is a^3 = to

Comment: You have confused a and x. In the first case you mean $(a^x)'$ with respect to $x$ and in the second case you mean $(a^3)'$ with respect to a. Isn't it so?

Comment: It is ok what your teacher said, but be careful according to which variable you are taking the derivative. $a$ is usually a number (called constant) and $x$ is the variable

Comment: I don't think that you *mean* what you have written.  It is true that *the derivative* of $a^x$ with respect to $x$ is $a^x \ln a$.  In other words, if $f(x) = a^x$, then $f'(x) = a^x \ln a$.

Comment: @Stefanos I was thinking a^3 with respect to 3

Comment: Ahh I see.. now !

Comment: Emanuel, you can write it as follows. $(a^x)'=a^xlna$, so for $x=3$ you have that it is equal to $a^3lna$. Do not say with respect to 3. Say with respect to x, for x=3.

Comment: Very nice and thank you very much for the quick help !! I really appreciate it ! Now everything makes much more sence

Answer (score 2):

First, a nitpick: the process of finding a derivative is called **differentiation**, not derivation.

What you learnt in class was that *the derivative of* $a^{x}$ *with respect to* $x$ is $a^{x}\ln(a)$.

So to suggest we apply the result 'when $x=3$' is wrong. We cannot differentiate with respect to $3$ because it is a constant, not a variable. If we differentiate $a^{3}$ with respect to $x$, then we simply get $0$ because $a^{3}$ is constant.

Another note: The usage of $a$ here may be confusing. It has been used as a placeholder for *any constant*, and should be treated as such. $x$, on the other hand, is understood to take any value for a given $a$ (it is a variable).

Comment: Yes this has cleared much of my misconceptions

Comment: Eloquently said !

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is a constant, then so is $a^3$, so the derivative of $a^3$ is $0$.

If you are evaluating the derivative of $f(x) = a^x\cdot \ln(x)$ at $x = 3$, then given we know by the rule for such general functions, $f'(x) = a^x\ln(a)$, and to evaluate this at $x = 3$ gives us $$f'(3) = a^3 \ln a$$ 
which is a constant value, and as soon as we know what $a$ is, we know $f'(3)$.

Comment: Hello, thanks you @amWhy for the reply. That is a nice answer. I just had one more question. What do you think a is in my question..

What do u think a is in the case of a^x = a^x.lna

Comment: Generally, when you see letters like $a$, $b$, they are being used to represent any constant.  You are given a rule for functions where a constant is being raised to a variable: $a^x$, like $3^x$.  The rule applies whatever constant $a$ happens to be.

Comment: Yes I see. Normally those letters are constants... but in the case where there is a constant and one of those letters such as : a^3 ... then logically a has to be the constant.

Comment: Yes, exactly: see my evaluation of $f'(3)$, where we indeed are assuming $a$ to be a constant (or a placeholder for a constant.) $$f(x) = a^x \implies f'(x) = a^x\ln a$$ is a *general rule* for any constant $a$ may represent.

Answer (score 0):

$(a^x)'=a^x \ln a$, then it is clear that the differentiation is with respect to $x$. Let's denote this function with $f$, so $f(x)=a^x$. Now, when you take $a^3$, it can be interpreted either as just a number (also considered as a constant function $g(x)=a^3$) or as $f(3)$.

Comment: Yes this is good... Now I am able to make the connection ! Thank you!